# SP2010 patching: psconfig after every patch or install a few then psconfig once?

Tags: 2010, patching

Can I install multiple updates on to my SharePoint 2010+SP2 farm (perhaps kb2553298, kb2878221, kb2878220) and just run psconfig once at the end or do I have to run psconfig after each patch?

Answer (score 1):

the patches you mentioned are security updates, Mostly security updates does not required the Config wizard( not true for all security updates).

apply the patches, Check from Central Admin > Manage servers in this farm and check if the status of the server saying upgrade required, if yes then you need to run the Config wizard. But in case if status is no action required then you all set without config wizard.

But for the CU and SP you need to run the config wizard after that these.

You can install both patches and then run the config wizard at the end.